# variables in extensions_custom.conf

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am using Queues to handle incoming calls which works pretty well.

What I would like to do now is to get the info which extensions has answered a call in "sub-queue-answer" context of extensions_custom.conf to hand over this information via CURL to another - e.g. CRM-server via:

```
exten => s,n,Set(foo=${CURL(https://hostname/voipcr.php?device=pbx1.xxx\&agent=${???}...)})
```

anyone any idea which variable can be set in the spaceholder of the three ??? to hand over the extension number of the agent who has answered that call?

Comment: why do you think it is doable via variables?

Comment: I don't know - that's why I ask ;-)
But due to the fact that more or less any other item can be found at this time (called Number, caller Number, and many more) - I think (hope) that someone can give me a hint how to catch the agent's extension (or any other identifier) at this time. 

If not it would also be fine if someone can give me another point where I can catch a real identifier of the agent who answers finally that call.

Comment: Check queue_log, or cdrs, or CEL.

Comment: queue_log does not provide the extension number, cdr ist written after the call is finished.

Comment: Queue_log works for all, except you. Sorry, nothing to add

Comment: I think, you need to have an AGI or AMI process to get what you need. Using AMI you can get the ['AgentConnect' event](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+18+ManagerEvent_AgentConnect) whan an agent get a call, then you can run your URL API.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that using extensions. Queues are sending calls to users without passing through the dialplan (a queue will call a agent directly).

To access data about who answered the call (and also when that happened) you need to listen for the [AgentConnect](https://docs.asterisk.org/Asterisk_16_Documentation/API_Documentation/AMI_Events/AgentConnect/?h=agentconnect) event on [Asterisk Manager Interface](https://docs.asterisk.org/Configuration/Interfaces/Asterisk-Manager-Interface-AMI/). As you can see in the documentation, the `AgentConnect` event will pass a lot of properties that you can parse, to extract the information you need. Probably you want to check `MemberName` and `Interface` properties, but that is subject to your particular setup.

Queue logs / CDR will help you only if you want to send the data after the call has been completed, but, to do that, you probably need to create a polling system (an undesirable solution, from my point of view).

Answer (score 0):

i usually use ${CUT(DIALEDPEERNUMBER,@,1)}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).